# Is it possible to create a python wheel from conda package?

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda, python-wheel

Im facing the following situation:

```
1. I wish to use TF 1.12 with MKL on windows
2. I have to use pip (our system supports only it so far)
```

problem is that currently Im unable to compile TF1.12 on windows (only on linux..).

I found that Conda has it right out of the box! so I was thinking 
"hmm lets take it from Conda, probably someone has thought about it :)"

never the less, havent find any package or program that can do it, so I've decided to use Stack-overflows' power to look for the solution.

any help in this subject would be really appreciated

Comment: this *could be* on topic here if you'd describe what exactly keeps you from compiling TF1.12 on windows.

Comment: Hi, this is why
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25213

Comment: that's annoying. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6396 seems to be related, I don't know about Bazel but they seem to have found a workaround using the WHOLEARCHIVE linker option.

Comment: The [`conda-press` utility](https://conda-incubator.github.io/conda-press-docs/index.html) seems like the tool for the job.